# Does passing a Table to a Stored Procedure incur multiple database calls?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have a large set of data. Now i am passing that data in the form of concatenated string with delimiters. In the stored procedure i am parsing the string and storing responses to table. Is this is the best approach OR passing Table to stored procedure is best approach.

I heard that passing table to stored procedure will incur multiple database calls for each row. Is this is true?

Comment: Just use the table. If nothing else, it's much cleaner. If - and *only when* - there is verified performance problem, then consider trying to "optimize" it. (If you absolutely do not want to use a TVF/TVP then at least use XML, which SQL Server supports fairly well, for the serialization format.)

Answer (score 2):

You mean table-valued parameters? No, it won't cause "multiple database calls for each row", it's just another way of passing a large chunk of data into a procedure.

Comment: "I heard that passing table to stored procedure will incur multiple database calls for each row." - but is *all* the data sent in a single "call" or across multiple (RPC) calls? And does it matter?

Comment: Yes to both questions.